# SQL Update Trigger not working as expected

Tags: oracle

I have an update trigger on my oracle table..but seems like it's not working..Schema under which triggers and table created is HR

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger TR_FinlStatAssetDesignation_U
BEFORE update
on FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATION FOR EACH ROW
   DECLARE
   v_AtDateTime  TIMESTAMP(3);
   v_LogOperation  NUMBER(3,0);
   v_UserName  VARCHAR2(255);
   v_AppName  VARCHAR2(255);
   SWV_error NUMBER(10,0) DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN

   begin
      select USERNAME INTO v_UserName FROM v$session  WHERE (audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','sessionid')) AND ROWNUM <=1;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
         NULL;
   end;

   SELECT program INTO v_AppName FROM v$session WHERE audsid=userenv('sessionid'); 
   if (LENGTH(v_AppName) = 0) then 
      v_AppName := 'Unknown';
   end if; 

   SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP INTO v_AtDateTime FROM dual;

   if UPDATING('FinlStatAssetDesignation') then
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'Invalid attempt to update OID FinlStatAssetDesignation in FinlStatAssetDesignation');
      /*    
      ROLLBACK */
      return;
   end if;

   if not UPDATING('UpdDate') then
      SWV_error := 0;
      begin
         UPDATE FinlStatAssetDesignation a SET(UpdDate) =(SELECT distinct v_AtDateTime FROM dual  where a.FinlStatAssetDesignation = :NEW.FinlStatAssetDesignation)
         WHERE ROWID IN(SELECT a.ROWID FROM FinlStatAssetDesignation a where a.FinlStatAssetDesignation = :NEW.FinlStatAssetDesignation);
         EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
            SWV_error := SQLCODE;
      end;
      if SWV_error <> 0 then
         /* 
ROLLBACK */
return;
```

In this trigger.. second part i.e below is not working of trigger..please help....it is not updating the timestamp in upddate column

```
SQL> select * from finlstatassetdesignation;

FINLSTATAS FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATIONDESC                       UPDOPERATION
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------
UPDDATE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
one19      anyt                                                          0
           hinh
01-JAN-17 08.00.00.000000 AM


SQL> update finlstatassetdesignation set finlstatassetdesignationdesc ='nothing';

1 row updated.

SQL> select * From finlstatassetdesignation;

FINLSTATAS FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATIONDESC                       UPDOPERATION
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ------------
UPDDATE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
one19      nothing                                                       0
01-JAN-17 08.00.00.000000 AM
```

Comment: Don't implement business logic with triggers -  its a bad practice.

Comment: `select   USERNAME INTO v_UserName FROM v$session  WHERE (audsid = SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','sessionid')) AND ROWNUM <=1;` can be simplified to `v_username := user;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish in the `ON INSERT` trigger? From your comment of

> I still can insert a row as user "hello"..hence trigger is not working..

you seem to want to prevent a user named `HELLO` from being added - but in your trigger code if a username of `HELLO` is found you simply return from the trigger. That doesn't accomplish anything. To signal to the system that you don't want the INSERT to proceed you must raise an exception in your trigger. For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Trigger TR_FinlStatAssetDesignation_I
  BEFORE Insert on FINLSTATASSETDESIGNATION
BEGIN
  if USER = 'HELLO' or USER = 'SYSTEM' then
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Invalid user in TR_FinlStatAssetDesignation_I');
  end if;
END TR_FinlStatAssetDesignation_I;
```

Raising an exception in this manner will prevent the INSERT from proceeding to successful completion. Your code is responsible for providing an appropriate error handler.

Best of luck.

Comment: You should also specify FOR EACH ROW. Else it is only statement trigger

Comment: Can anyone help on the update trigger as it still isnt sorted out for me?